# How to get all children of parent node?

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a DTO as below:

```
 class TreeLevel
 {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long? ParentId { get; set; }
 }
```

And I have a simple list of this DTO:

```
var list = new List<TreeLevel>() {
            new TreeLevel  {
               Id=1,
               ParentId=null
            },
            new TreeLevel{
                Id=2,
                ParentId=1
            },
            new TreeLevel{
                Id=3,
                ParentId=1
            },
            new TreeLevel{
                Id=4,
                ParentId=2
            },
            new TreeLevel{
                Id=5,
                ParentId=8
            },
            new TreeLevel{
                Id=6,
                ParentId=null
            },
            new TreeLevel{
                Id=7,
                ParentId=null
            },
            new TreeLevel{
                Id=8,
                ParentId=4
            },
            new TreeLevel{
                Id=9,
                ParentId=10
            },
            new TreeLevel{
                Id=10,
                ParentId=8
            }
        };
```

I want to get all children (included children of child) .

For example I want get all children of Id=8 item.

Result must be:

```
5, 9, 10
```

How can I achive this ? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Could result be 5, 10, 9?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes, because parent of 5 is 8, parent of 10 is 8, and parent of 9 is 10. 10's parent is 8. Therefore all children must be 5,9,10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written the TraverseTree routine below that recursively walks the tree and returns the result as a IEnumerable<>.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace GetAllChildren
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<TreeLevel>()
            {
                new TreeLevel  { Id=1, ParentId=null },
                new TreeLevel{ Id=2, ParentId=1 },
                new TreeLevel{ Id=3, ParentId=1 },
                new TreeLevel{ Id=4, ParentId=2 },
                new TreeLevel{ Id=5, ParentId=8 },
                new TreeLevel{ Id=6, ParentId=null },
                new TreeLevel{ Id=7, ParentId=null },
                new TreeLevel{ Id=8, ParentId=4 },
                new TreeLevel{ Id=9, ParentId=10 },
                new TreeLevel{ Id=10, ParentId=8 }
            };

            var result = TraverseTree(list, 8).ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count(); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{result[i].Id} - {result[i].ParentId}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<TreeLevel> TraverseTree(List<TreeLevel> list, long id)
        {
            return list
                .Where(child => child.ParentId == id)
                .Union(list.Where(child => child.ParentId == id)
                .SelectMany(parent => TraverseTree(list, parent.Id))
            );
        }
    }

    class TreeLevel
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long? ParentId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The result of this code is:

---

```
5 - 8
10 - 8
9 - 10
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Will update answer if find a way to optimize it, does its job for now

```
var allNodes = new List<TreeLevel>();
var parentNodes = list.Where(x => x.Id == 8).ToList();

do
{
    foreach (var item in parentNodes) 
    {
        list.Remove(item); // to avoid loops in graph
    }

    var childNodes = new List<TreeLevel>();

    foreach (var parentId in parentNodes.Select(x => x.Id).Distinct())
    {
        childNodes.AddRange(list.Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId));
    }

    allNodes.AddRange(childNodes);
    parentNodes = childNodes;

} while (parentNodes.Any());
```